# Изменение IP адресса и DNS Браузера. (PROXY)

Tags: ip, proxy, dns

Купил IP адресс (Россия):
`146.185.211.143:4060`

Меняю на компьютере:

[image: Настройка IP]

Захожу на сайт для проверки IP : https://whoer.net/ru#

Все отлично, IP сменился, но на сайт показывает плохую анонимность из-за того, что 
DNS отличается (Страна расположения вашего DNS сервера отличается от страны расположения вашего IP-адреса. )

Меняю автоматические DNS на DNS Яндекса:

[image: Настройка DNS]

`77.88.8.8

77.88.8.1`

Опять захожу на сайт: https://whoer.net/ru#
Ожидаю увидеть смену `DNS Яндекса`, но `DNS Финские`:

[image: Неправильный DNS]

Что делать? Почему не изменились DNS, я же их в настройках поменял?

При этом замечено, если не менять IP адрес, при смене DNS с автоматических на DNS от  Яндекса, DNS меняются. Т.е. получается дело в изменении настроек  IP адрес?
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в чем дело?

Comment: "ip адрес" вы хреновый купили. вернее, прокси это называется

Comment: хорош айпи-адрес с портом :)

Comment: Меняйте логин с паролем, они все равно видны будут, даже если вопрос удалите ;)

Comment: Кабель от провайдера подключен на прямую в ПК или в роутер?

Comment: Пароли и логины не жалко, важно разобраться в ситуации, чтобы не было вопрос, мол плохой купили  и т.д., поэтому отправил все) Кабель подключен через фай-фай

Comment: DNS смените в WiFi роутере. В качестве браузера у вас хром я так понимаю. Я бы посоветовал Firefox.

Comment: Я нифига не анонимен, но мне выдаёт то же самое и тот же DNS, хотя я его вообще-то не использую. По-моему это просто сайт кривой

Comment: `Ваша анонимность: 100% Ваши средства анонимность надежны, либо вы их не используете`

Comment: @excellproj по-твоему, роутер переопределяет DNS запрос? Кстати провайдер может DNS запрос переопределять. Можно использовать DNSSEC.

Comment: У меня адрес DNS поменялся. `74.125.0.0/16` это подсеть Google.

Comment: А вот интересно как сайт определяет днс?

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понимаю, при обращении через прокси, адрес ресолвится самим прокси, соотсетственно DNS-сервер надо настраивать не на своём компе, а на прокси-сервере.