# Как веб-страница получает информацию о DNS?

Tags: javascript, dns, браузер

Вот читал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/732926/16574) и возник новый. Как на веб-странице определить используемые dns сервера? Есть какое-то апи на яваскрипт? Как отключить эту возможность?

https://whoer.net/ru например

Comment: 1. насколько я вижу, информация о dns-сервере не имеет ни малейшего отношения к реальности. 2. если бы я **честно** реалиовывал такую проверку, то просто добавил бы в код страницы обращение к уникальному, при каждой загрузке страницы генерируемому url (img, script и т.п.), dns-запрос на который обслуживал бы мой dns-сервер. а от него информация о том, с какого ip был сделан dns-запрос, поступала бы моему http-серверу, который и передавал бы её javascript-у, крутящемуся в браузере. как-то так.

Comment: 1. днс могут ресолвиться по цепочке...завтра покопаем

Comment: @alexanderbarakin судя по мониторингу сети, что-то подобное и происходит, только глючит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как на веб-странице определить используемые dns сервера?

«по-простому», средствами только содержимого страницы — никак

> Есть какое-то апи на яваскрипт?

насколько мне известно, нет

> Как отключить эту возможность?

увы, «возможность» добавить в код страницы какой-либо html-элемент (img, script) с адресом, содержащим уникальное генерируемое при каждом запросе страницы доменное имя, в общем случае «отключить» невозможно.

соответственно невозможно избежать dns-запроса для резолвинга этого уникального имени, соответственно невозможно «не дать знать» dns-серверу, обслуживающему зону, которой принадлежит это имя, откуда (с какого ip-адреса) пришёл к нему запрос на резолвинг этого имени.

можно разве что отключить java-скрипт, который эту **уже полученную** (свзякой из dns- и http-серверов) информацию отображает на веб-странице.